# how to add mongodb replica Set in spring boot project

Tags: spring-mongodb, spring-mongo, mongodb-replica-set

i am new to mongodb repleca set

> spring boot **2.2.2**
>
> mongo db driver **3.12.1**

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://user:pass@server1:27017,server2:27017,server3:27017/DB?replicaSet=‌mongodb_rs
```

always getting the following error while fetching data from DB

> 19-02-2020 12:05:27.753 [http-nio-2053-exec-1] INFO  org.mongodb.driver.cluster.info - No server chosen by com.mongodb.client.internal.MongoClientDelegate$1@594215be from cluster description ClusterDescription{type=REPLICA_SET, connectionMode=MULTIPLE, serverDescriptions=[]}. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out

Comment: Have you found a solution by any chance? I'm having a similar problem.

Comment: did either find a solution?